# How to convert an array of dates (format 'mm/dd/yy HH:MM:SS') to numerics?

Tags: python, date, time

I have recently (1 week) decided to migrate my work to Python from matlab. Since I am used to matlab, I am finding it difficult sometimes to get the exact equivalent of what I want to do in python.

Here's my problem:

I have a set of csv files that I want to process. So far, I have succeeded in loading them into groups. Each column has a size of more 600000 x 1. In one of the columns in the csv file is the time which has a format of 'mm/dd/yy HH:MM:SS'. I want to convert the time column to number and I am using date2num from matplot lib for that. Is there a 'matrix' way of doing it? The command in matlab for doing that is datenum(time, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS') where time is a 600000 x 1 matrix.

Thanks

Here is an example of the code that I am talking about:

```
import csv
import time
import datetime from datetime
import date from matplotlib.dates
import date2num

time = []
otherColumns = []

for d in csv.DictReader(open('MyFile.csv')):
      time.append(str(d['time']))
      otherColumns.append(float(d['otherColumns']))

timeNumeric = date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(time,"%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S" ))
```

Comment: You may find http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users very useful.

Comment: [`pandas.io.parsers.read_csv()`](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/io.html) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a generator:

```
def pre_process(dict_sequence):
    for d in dict_sequence:
        d['time'] = date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(d['time'],"%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S" ))
    yield d
```

now you can process your csv:

```
for d in pre_process(csv.DictReader(open('MyFile.csv'))):
    process(d)
```

the advantage of this solution is that it doesn't copy sequences that are potentially large.

**Edit:**

So you the contents of the file in a numpy array?

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('MyFile.csv'))
#you might want to get rid of the intermediate list if the file is really big.
data = numpy.array(list(d.values() for d in pre_process(reader)))
```

Now you have a nice big array that allows all kinds of operations. You want only the first column to get your 600000x1 matrix:

```
data[:,0]  # assuming time is the first column
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this solution, however this just gives me a numerical time with size of 1x1. What I was trying to do is to have an array of 600000x1 for the numerical time so that I can do the necessary matrix operations using numpy/scipy. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have enough reputation yet to upvote you. I marked it however as an accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing in Python for matlab's matrix/vector operation is list comprehension. If you would like to apply a Python function on each item in a list you could do:

```
new_list = [date2num(data) for data in old_list]
```

or

```
new_list = map(date2num, old_list)
```